# Mixing data(types) and elements in Relax NG

Tags: relaxng, relaxng-compact

I am trying to define a Relax NG compact syntax model for the following content:

```
<coordinates class="blue">-132.976733 56.437924 <span class="red">-132.735747 56.459832 -132.631685 56.421493 -132.664547 56.273616</span> -132.878148 56.240754 -133.069841 56.333862 -132.976733 56.437924</coordinates>
```

Where the  element could wrap one or more coordinate pairs, and could indeed have nested  elements with the same content model.

Is this possible?  I read [here](https://relaxng.org/compact-tutorial-20030326.html#id2814737) that it may not be possible using, for example xsd:double.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this question is the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5044787/relaxng-invalid-schema-definition), so I'm going to guess the answer is similar, something like "No, use the 'mixed' pattern, then Schematron the datatype constraints on the tokens".